# Erro: readdir() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Tags: php

Como faço para retornar um valor vazio no comando `opendir($dir);` em php?
Gostaria que quando não houver uma pasta, retorne com o valor zero, pois está dando erro:

> readdir() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

Quando não existe uma pasta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seguindo o [manual do PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.opendir.php), o código pode ser assim:

```
<?php

 $dir = "/etc/php5/"; 

 // Abre um diretorio conhecido, e faz a leitura de seu conteudo
 if (is_dir($dir)) {
    if ($dh = opendir($dir)) { // <-- AQUI VALIDA  SE RETORNA ALGO
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
            echo "filename: $file : filetype: " . filetype($dir . $file) . "\n";
        }
        closedir($dh);
    }
 }
?>
```

Se o trecho: `$dh = opendir($dir)` não achar nada retorna `FALSE`.